# Access the image URLs using Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape information about houses from this website:https://www.goldenproperty.co.za/property_search_result.aspx?type=allTypes&min_price=0&max_price=1000000000&beds=-1&baths=-1&ids=Cape%20Town.all%20suburbs&status=-1&sqm=-1&land=-1

Specifically, I would want to extract the URL of the images of each property that is listed on the results page.

This part of the code should get the images. However, due to them being available on the child page, I only get GET https://www.goldenproperty.co.za/property/for-sale/tamboerskloof/retail-for-sale_1016735/ rather than the actual URL of the image.

```
   def parse(self, response):
        for prop in response.css('div.search_result_panel'):
            link = prop.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            request = scrapy.Request(link, callback = self.get_loc)

            yield {
                .....
                other fields we're extracting                
                .....

                'images': request
            }
    def get_loc(self,response):
        div = response.css('div.visible-print')
        pics = div.css('img::attr(src)').getall()
        return pics
```

We want the yield list/dictionary of all the image URLs for each property. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the URLs you need are only available on the item page(child), you need to make a request first, and grab those URLs on `get_loc`.

If you want to pass info from the search to the item page, you can do it passing your item as `meta` on request, and then yield the item there with all image URL.

```
   def parse(self, response):
        for prop in response.css('div.search_result_panel'):
            link = prop.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            yield scrapy.Request(
                link,
                meta={'item': {'other_fields': other_values}},
                callback=self.get_loc,
            )

    def get_loc(self,response):
        item = response.meta.get('item')
        div = response.css('div.visible-print')
        item['images'] = div.css('img::attr(src)').getall()
        yield item
```

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.meta